# Split lines in a file using shell script

Tags: shell, sh

Im having a file which contains data in the below format.

```
<data1/><data2/><data3/>.........<dataN/>
```

How can i convert the data into the below format

```
<data1/>
<data2/>
<data3/>
.........
<dataN/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep -o` you can do:

```
grep -o '<[^>]*>' file
<data1/>
<data2/>
<data3/>
<dataN/>
```

Comment: Its gives me a message `Binary file file.csv matches`

Comment: @dhanishjose this problem seems to be related with encoding differences between windows (UTF-16) and linux (UTF-8), assuming your csv files were created with windows. This should be why `grep` thinks your csv file is binary. Try adding the `-a` flag to your grep command. Alternatly, you can try opening your csv file with gedit and saving it again, to revert encoding back to UTF-8

Comment: @dhanishjose: As Ploutox said you can use: `grep -mo '<[^>]*>' file` command.

Comment: Thanks, i got the desired output with `-a` option.